# Obtener mensaje AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

Buenas tardes,

Estoy haciendo una validacion de Usuario, pero no logro recibir el mensaje que obtengo. Tengo lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#UEmail").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ValidarCorreo.jsp",
      data: {
             Correo: $("#UEmail").val()
             }
     })
       .done(function (msg) {
                                    
       if(msg==="true")
       {
         //Mostrar mensaje
        }
                                    
      });
     });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Correo Electronico:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <div class="input-group m-b">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
         <input name="UEmail" id="UEmail" required type="text" class="form-control required email" placeholder="">
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

la variable msg lo que contiene es el siguiente HTML:

```
"↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵    <head>↵        <meta http-
equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">↵        <title>JSP 
Page</title>↵        ↵    </head>↵    <body>↵        false↵    
</body>↵</html>↵"
```

Esto contiene mi JSP:

```
 <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
       <%!
           String Correo;
       %>
</head>
<body>
    <%
      Correo=request.getParameter("Correo");

        if(Correo=="alguno@hotmail.com")
        {
            out.print("true");
        }
        else
        {
            out.print("false");
        }
    %>
</body>
```

Comment: Porque no pruebas retornando el elemento en formato JSON o XML o es necesario ese formato de respuesta??

Comment: @JoseAntonioDominguezGarcia No es necesario, solo que es la primera vez que uso AJAX y no sabria como retornarlo en esos formatos.

Comment: ¿El _JSP_ es parte del problema?

Comment: mira tienes que enviar los valores en formato JSON o XML desde el servidor una vez enviados asi los recuperas y los conviertes en un array desde javascript y ya puedes manipular el objeto a tu necesidad.

Answer (score 1):

El resultado de una respuesta `ajax` se recupera en la propiedad `success` de la llamada `ajax`.

Tu petición ajax debería ser asi:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      //Esto define el tipo que dato que esperas recibir
      dataType:"text/html",
      url: "ValidarCorreo.jsp",
      data: {
         Correo: $("#UEmail").val()
      },
      success: function(response){
        //En response estaría el resultado que envías de tu jsp
      }
     })
```

**UPDATE**

El otro gran problema entra en como estas mandando los datos del servidor.

```
<head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
       <%!
           String Correo;
       %>
</head>
<body>
    <%
      //Declaramos el Printwriter, donde escribiremos nuestra respuesta
      que es lo que la llamada espera leer de vuelta
      PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
      //Le decimos que lo que vamos a devolver es de tipo texto (coincidendo 
      //con el declaro en la llamda ajax)
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

      Correo=request.getParameter("Correo");

        if(Correo=="alguno@hotmail.com")
        {
            //Escribimos la respuesta en el buffer
            writer.println("true");
        }
        else
        {
            //Escribimos la respuesta en el buffer
            writer.println("false");
        }
        //Hacemos un flush para indicar que hemos termiando de escribir y 
        //queremos que se envie la respuesta
        writer.flush();
    %>
</body>
```

De todas formas, mencionarte que no es buena practica realizar operaciones `ajax` a un `jsp` directamente, deberías hacer una llamada a un `Servlet` y desde ahí  realizar las operaciones lógicas necesarias.

Comment: Hola, gracias, pero sigue aun sin funcionarme, no se si esque esta mal como estoy devolviendo la respuesta desde el servidor

Comment: response me sigue guardando el HTML y no el valor (false, true) que es lo que necesito.

Answer (score 1):

tienes que usar la funcion `submit` en un input para enviar los datos a tu archivo PHP ó jsp y creo un  para ver el resultados que se envia por un post
ejemplo PHP

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['UEmail'];
echo $data;
?>
```

**code ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').on('submit', '#UEmail', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var DataString = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        var search = $("#UEmail").val();


 $.ajax({
                url: 'ValidarCorreo.jsp',
                type: 'POST',
                data: DataString,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function () {

                $('#searcbtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#resultados").html(data).show();

                } 
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira estas enviando mal tu respuesta desde el servidor lo que tienes que hacer es enviar un formato valido que puedas convertir del lado del cliente con Javascript ¿Y como lo haces? Para realizar esto del lado del servidor tienes que ocupar una tecnología como JSON o XML dependiendo de tus gusto aunque sinceramente creo yo que por eficiencia JSON es mejor.
Mediante el siguiente [Link](https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso), puedes comprender un poco mas acerca de como enviarlas y tratarlas.
Espero te ayude saludos.